# Widget's rebuild condition in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Does the widget rebuild even if the value of the StatelessWidget is the same?

```dart
/// In this case it is a `const` widget so it will not be rebuilt.
const Text("hi") // not rebuild.
```

```dart
/// The text has changed, so it will rebuild.
String text = "hi"

Text(text)

setState(() {
    text = "hello"  // Text rebuild.
});
```

```dart
/// Does the Text widget rebuild here?
String text = "hi"

Text(text)

setState(() {
    // nothing or text = "hi";
});
```

Does the Text widget rebuild when text is not changed or changed to the same value?

Comment: Yes, even if you call `setState(() {})` the widget becomes dirty and will be rebuilded.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it was rebuilt or not by adding DateTime.now() in Text

```
/// Does the Text widget rebuild here?
String text = "hi"

Text('text ${DateTime.now()}')

setState(() {
    // nothing or text = "hi";
});
```

If rebuilt Text will return new IU